# Hiding a subterranean alien megastructure

Tags: internal-consistency, earth, megastructures

I need to know if it’d be possible for a underground ring-like structure of immense proportions and alien design to go unnoticed by modern day sonar, radar, and geological surveying.

For an idea of size, imagine a tunnel about the ***width of a football field*** or bigger (maybe *100-200 meters* in diameter) that’s buried ***2- 5 kilometers underground*** and ***wraps around the entire planet*** (giving it a circumference of *40000 km*).

Could something like this remain hidden until a mining project accidentally uncovers it in Africa, or would something this size have been detected by now with the technology developed in the 20th and 21st centuries?

Comment: When would it have been built? Even within a single lifetime, tectonic plates move up to a meter.

Comment: I believe [there's one below a city in US](http://animorphs.wikia.com/wiki/Yeerk_Pool)

Comment: As an additional point you might want to consider, were the builders wanting to keep it hidden? If they were then it might be very difficult to detect as they could have manipulated the immediate surroundings to masks its presence by using various densities and configurations of rock or other materials to confuse.

Comment: Where did they put all the excavated dirt and rock? That is a LOT of stuff to move around. Maybe that is where the moon actually came from? Tailings from this tunnel?

Comment: @JustinThyme - where did they put the dirt and rock?  Why, outside the tunnel, of course :-).  400ft x 400ft x 40000km = 3.34E+11 cubic meters.  The rockies are 4800 km long and range up to 300 miles wide.  Say average it at 200 km wide, you have an area 9.6E+11 squared meters.  Sprinkle the dirt from the tunnel over the rockies and you raise their height by 30 cm or so.  Heck, sprinkle it all over earth's landmass, to avoid messing with earth's center of gravity too much, and you'd raise the ground level by less than a millimeter.

Comment: @JustinThyme - by the way, the volume of dirt and rock would be a little more than one thousandth of one percent of the volume of the moon.  334 billion cubic meters of dirt and rock seems like a LOT, but on a planetary scale it is a trifle.

Comment: @AgapwIesu Mount Everest is apparently 595 million cubic meters, give or take, Compared to your calculated pile of 334 billion cubic meters, this pile is 571 Mount Everests. They would, indeed, have to spread it out. Or maybe dump it in the ocean. The volume of the moon is 2.9e16, only 100,000 times greater. A paltry difference.Maybe they dug a LOT of tunnels.

Comment: @JustinThyme - where are you getting 595 million cubic meters for the volume of Mount everest?  Mount Everest has a volume, only counting from base camp, of 2.1 trillion cubic feet = 2.1E+12.  In cubic meters, that is 5.95E+10 cubic meters, or 59.5 billion cubic meters, 100 times bigger than what you said.  The dirt from that tunnel would only be about 5.5 times the size of mount Everest (from base camp up), or have I misplaced a decimal point somewhere?

Comment: @AgapwIesu I have gone through your math, and apparently it was I who missed a few decimal places, if your volume of 2.1 trillion cubic feet is approximately correct. Assuming a height of 11,500 feet. and radius of 2.5 miles by my recalculations it seems close enough. But five Mount Everests is still a lot of dirt.

Comment: @ AgapwIesu But I am having some conversion problems with your 400ft X 400ft X 40000km starting figures.

Comment: Note that aliens might have to to use some supermaterials for their tunnel , because pressure and heat increases as you go deeper [ at around 25C per km away from boundaries, according to Wikipedia], up to the point where it eg. crushes the drilling equipment. Humans haven't been able to drill deeper than 12km (40k feet): https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Scientific_drilling

Comment: @JustinThyme - The 2.1 Trillion cubic feet is what you get if you google "volume of Everest".  The 400ft is a bit more than OP's first spec (length of a football field) which is 300 ft.  400 ft is approximately 91 m.  91m x 91m will give you a cross section of about 8281 square meters (8.3E+3).  OP stated circumference of earth as 40000 km, so 4.0E+7 meters.  Although the shape is actually a toroid, the ratio of radius to width is so high that a straight multiplication is ok = 33.2E+10 or 3.32E+11 or 332 billion cubic meters.

Comment: @JustinThyme and on a planetary scale, 6 mount everests are not much.  Consider that if you draw a circle, as big as possible on your computer screen (2k pixels maybe), Mount Everest, from base to peak, would be a blip about half a pixel tall.  The point is, especially compared with the technological hurdles for drilling that deep and maintaining such a structure, disposal of the excess dirt is the least of your problems.

Comment: @AgapwIesu  I see my conversion  problem. 400 feet is 122 meters but 300 feet is 91 meters.and change. Okay, so I am making a mountain out of a mole hill. Or rather a moon out of a mountain.

Comment: There's been a documentary about such a subterranean mega structure back in 2004. It was called the Bouvetøya Island expedition 
It remained hidden until someone switched on the lights:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_vs._Predator_(film)

Answer (score 49):

Consider the following:

- The diameter of the Earth is ***12,742 kilometers***.
- Our planet's crust thickness is anywhere from ***30 kilometers*** on the continents, to ***5 - 10 kilometers*** on the ocean floors (which have not been explored or mined in any real detail).
- The deepest mine on the planet goes down less than ***4 kilometers***.
- Your average ground penetrating radar does so at a depth of 30 meters (this will obviously vary with the system and material it has to travel through).

Keeping all this in mind, I wouldn't be surprised if such a tunnel ***did in fact exist***. Even with today's technology, it might not be found for hundreds of years, if ever.

Remember, that even if your detection technology is pretty amazing, you still have to be ***looking at relatively specific location*** to find it. We don't go around ground scanning every random location on the planet, especially not at any considerable depth.

Simply place it slightly deeper than we've gone, and you're golden. In the not too far future advances in material science and automation may result in robots being built which can mine to greater depths than we've been able to achieve so far, and stumble onto it.

Comment: This is a good answer.  Indeed, +1 just for pointing out that our ground-penetrating capabilities are so limited today that such a structure could exist and we'd never know it.  There's so much mass involved and so little is actually known about the depths of the earth that I can't even think of a way to find such a structure mathematically.  Thanks!

Comment: +1 for putting the problem in perspective. Just a note: the tunnel should not come anywhere near an oil field, or an area suspected to have oil, or any other area where systematic seismic surveying is done.

Comment: It's true that ground radar penetration is short, but seismic methods are a lot more penetrating, specially when analyzing seismic waves from natural earthquakes. We need just to realize that seismic techniques have been used to map the Earth's core.

Comment: @Pere: not to 100-200 m resolution though. That would be like finding a hair in your soup by tapping the bowl with a spoon.

Comment: @JoeBloggs You have a point that resolution is challenging.

Comment: I have to echo the criticism, this answer is just wrong. Ground-penetrating radar is a straw example, that's only used for investigating details of small structures near the surface (except in some special cases; e.g. in a ice shelf, GPR reaches much further). Geophysicists have plenty of other methods, most of which reach much further, and though they indeed don't offer such a great resolution as GPR, it would be plenty enough for noticing a 100 m cavity.

Comment: @JoeBloggs “Hair in a bowl of soup” is not comparable at all, because **a)** that's vastly exaggerating the size proportions (Øhair:bowl ≈ 1:1000, vs. Øtunnel:depth ≈ 1:50), **b)** the hair has roughly the same density as the soup around it and can therefore just transmit any waves, whereas the tunnel has a completely different density from the surrounding matter, which means it would strongly scatter any seismic waves. Indeed you would not be able to exactly measure the tunnel from the surface, but you'd damn sure _notice there's something extremely funny down there_.

Comment: ...also: I suspect you _could_ actually find a hair by tapping the bowl and very carefully evaluating the surface waves.

Comment: @leftroundabout: Detecting the discontinuity between bowl/soup is very easy because, as you noted, the difference in densities scatters the waves strongly at all points along the plane. The tunnel would be a lot harder to find because only a thin strand would scatter, making it very easy to lose among general noise. I’m sure that it is possible to find a hair (or noodle, if you prefer that ratio) in a bowl of soup, but doing so when there are bay leaves, bits of ham, croutons and you don’t know what’s in the soup in the first place is an awful lot harder.

Comment: @JoeBloggs, your concept of resolution is wrong: something will not appear in a geophysics survey if it's below the resolution of the survey in *all* dimensions, not just one. A 100 meter by 100 meter by 100 meter cavity may not show up on a survey that has a resolution of a kilometer: a 100 meter by 100 meter by 40,000 km cavity certainly will. To use an example, Landsat satellites have a resolution of 30 meters in visible light, but you can pick out roads and linear features longer than 30 meters easily as long as there's sufficient contrast between the feature and the surrounding terrain.

Comment: For the record, if you put an ultrasound probe into a bowl of water, you can absolutely see hairs and other such detritus floating around.

Comment: @KeithMorrison: I was under the impression that seismology required a plane to work with (ie feature > resolution in at least 2 dimensions). Turns out not so much. Today I have learned things.

Comment: @JoeBloggs, you can spot something smaller than the resolution in *all* dimensions if it produces a strong enough signal.  For example, every star out there is smaller than the resolving power of the human eye, yet it's quite possible to see them.

Comment: To use an even more everyday example: the width of a thick human hair is 50 microns. If you cut a piece of hair so that its length was also 50 microns, odds are you're not going to be able to see it unless you looked very closely in very good light, so that 50 micron long cylinder is unlikely to be seen in your soup. On the other hand, a 5 centimeter long hair of the same diameter can be seen easily.

Answer (score 41):

The Earth is better surveyed than is generally realized. It is probable that geophysical survey techniques would have revealed the existence of an underground megastructure.

> Geophysical surveys may use a great variety of sensing instruments, and data may be collected from above or below the Earth's surface or from aerial, orbital, or marine platforms. Geophysical surveys have many applications in geology, archaeology, mineral and energy exploration, oceanography, and engineering. Geophysical surveys are used in industry as well as for academic research.

There is a wide variety and considerable spectrum of instruments used for geophysical surveys.

> Seismic methods, such as reflection seismology, seismic refraction, and seismic tomography.
>
> Seismoelectrical method
>
> Geodesy and gravity techniques, including gravimetry and gravity gradiometry.
>
> Magnetic techniques, including aeromagnetic surveys and magnetometers.
>
> Electrical techniques, including electrical resistivity tomography, induced polarization, spontaneous potential and marine control source electromagnetic (mCSEM) or EM seabed logging.
>
> Electromagnetic methods, such as magnetotellurics, ground penetrating radar and transient/time-domain electromagnetics, magnetic resonance sounding (MRS).
>
> Borehole geophysics, also called well logging.
>
> Remote sensing techniques, including hyperspectral.

Source: [Geophysical survey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geophysical_survey)

Many of these instruments and techniques could reveal a deep subterranean structure depending on the nature and construction of the megastructure.

For example, because of its depth the world-girdling tunnels would need to be made of extremely strong and, possibly, dense materials. Gravimetric surveys might detect its presence. Magnetomtric surveys would the same if its construction material(s) were highly magnetic.

Remote sensing imagery could show a continuous band of disturbance or its remnants if earth rock and soil had to be displaced for the megastructure's construction and installation. Building something on this scale at a depth of kilometres will leave its mark on the planet.

[Remote sensing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_sensing), orbital and aerial imaging are excellent at uncovering changes to the surface and subsurface of planetary terrain. Changes or structures that wouldn't be apparent if you were standing in those places yourself.

The ring megastructure is likely to be detected by variations in mass distribution using geodetic remote sensing.

> Geodetic remote sensing can be gravimetric or geometric. Overhead gravity data collection was first used in aerial submarine detection. This data revealed minute perturbations in the Earth’s gravitational field that may be used to determine changes in the mass distribution of the Earth, which in turn may be used for geophysical studies, as in GRACE (satellite). Geometric remote sensing includes position and deformation imaging using InSAR, LIDAR, etc

There is also seismic mapping of the Earth's interior which might determine there was two hundred metre diameter tunnel around the world.

While a mine or a bore hole breaking through or hitting the megastructure is more hit or miss geophysics has an arsenal of methods and instruments to survey what is down below the surface of our planet.

In summary, there a wide range of geophysical survey methods. Many of which, both singly or together, could indicate the presence of a subterranean megastructure. Once its existence was suspected the range of geophysical instruments could be brought to beat to further elucidate it. In principle, puny humans have the techniques to find a deep megastructure and have had them since the twentieth century, therefore, they can only be expected to have gotten better this century. This makes the discovery of the megastructure highly probable.

Answer (score 11):

I must disagree with AndreiROM on this.  I believe it would have been found some time ago.

I'm thinking specifically of oil exploration.  They go all over the place looking at subterranean layout to figure out where it's worthwhile to drill for oil.  If it's drillable they're going to have a look--and your loop is certainly going to pass through some drillable areas.

About the only way I think it could be missed is if it never went near geologic features that could possibly contain oil.  It still would have been seen but it might not be noticed if the survey crew stopped looking because they knew it wasn't oil.  (The Chicxulub crater was missed this way--the oil guys saw it in the 1950s but dismissed it as volcanic, no chance of oil, they never looked at it closely enough to realize what they were seeing.)

Comment: There's a point to be made here.  In 2009 the [Deepwater Horizon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deepwater_Horizon) drilled the deepest well at 10Km.  However, the OP need only push his creation deeper still to solve the problem.  Further, Adrei's point about needing to look at a specific location could still keep it hidden.  Given the OP's design, it's a needle in a haystack.  Great point, though.

Comment: If I were to plan such a megastructure, I would try to avoid anything near oil to not have to fear a problem of that stuff seeping in.

Comment: "Hey, there's a weird reading; a straight line running due east-west." "Oh? Right, that. Yeah you see that a lot at this latitude; it's just air. But that patch over there might be worth something." Airplane pilots were seeing colored lightning off the tops of clouds for 50 years before telling anyone who cared.

Comment: @PlasmaHH It's not just oil, but anything the oil guys would think **might** contain oil.

Comment: @JBH Deepwater Horizon was the deepest oil well; other exploration borings have gone as deep, the deepest being 12.2 Km (the [Kola Superdeep Borehole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kola_Superdeep_Borehole)). I was thinking that this might be deeper than was useful, given it's nearly halfway through the Earth's crust, but perhaps the heat from the mantle is being used as a energy source.

Comment: @brichins, that's a great idea!

Answer (score 11):

You have a very big problem with your 2-5 km. depth. The average depth of the Atlantic ocean is over 3 km. I suspect it would have to be deeper than 5 km., and it would not be a perfect ring.

And forget about around the equator. If you went pole to pole, along roughly 30 degrees west - 150 degrees east longitude, you pretty much miss all land mass and drilling sites. It's ocean all the way, except for a piece of Australia. Since we have done very little in the way of exploring this region, it would be virtually undetectable by current methods. It misses a lot of volcanic activity as well.

Tectonic plate shifting would be a problem no matter where you put it. There would be tremendous sheer forces between plates.

Earthquakes can be as deep as 700 km. or more.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer to the question.

Comment: I was about to answer the same, so I will upvote and comment here. @JustinTyme: you may want to edit your answer to be a bit more "answer-like", something along the lines: "It may remain unnoticed if... but structural integrity would be difficult due to tectonic plaques movement...". It is interesting to note there's a Earth circumference (cape Horn, Africa Pakistan, Corea) where plate movement is roughly along the circle ;)

Comment: @ MichaelK Using the 30 degree west - 150 degree east longitude is an answer and a solution. A virtually undetectable place to put such a ring.

Comment: If you don't mind it being torn apart by crossing multiple spreading centers, subduction zones, and plates moving in opposite directions.

Comment: @ Keith Morrison Maybe they are residents from Myst.

Answer (score 10):

We have a pretty good idea of the *general* layout of the Earth core from seismic data. [Seismometers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seismometer) are used to track earthquakes and nuclear tests. These [models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_model) have been developed by reconciling theoretical physics and experimental data.

So if there was such a tunnel, and if the tunnel is under the equator, it might show up in the model as the "equatorial anomaly" or "equatorial subduction zone." Yes, there are strange echoes. No, they can't possibly be a tunnel. *A density anomaly.* Some physicist comes up with an explanation, the explanation fits the experimental data, the theory is provisionally accepted, and mankind has wrong ideas about the contents of Earth.

Say they think the core is (or was?) more fluid than we think, and coriolis forces must have concentrated high density (or low density) materials in patterns, much like the [cloud bands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jupiter#Atmosphere) of Jupiter.

Alternatively, the data gets explained away as something like a [mascon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_concentration_(astronomy)).

Comment: Yes, however this would be a very significant anomaly, and unlike a mascon we could use plenty of different methods to investigate it. Perform a joint inversion of gravimetry, seismic and magnetotellurics, and you'd see that it's very sharply localised and with _very_ exotic properties. That would easily warrant a large-scale drilling operation to nail down what's up there†, even if it would be very expensive. Pretty sure some country would have done that no later than 1980 (Kola reached 12 km in 1979). — — — — — — — — — — — — — † _(Or should I say: “to screw up what's down there”?)_

Comment: @leftaroundabout, there is *some* merit to what you say, but in order to define an anomaly you need a baseline for normal. If the megastructure predates scientific investigation, it is part of that baseline. Consider just how sharply the ridges of the moon Europa are drawn -- we are quite confident they are natural.

Comment: That's....that's not how it works. A negative density anomaly, which such a tunnel would be, arranged in a linear fashion circling the entire globe would immediately raise issues because common sense would indicate it shouldn't be there. Look at it this way: if you saw a tunnel composed of nothing but air going for kilometers through a lake, would you assume that's "natural" just because it had "always been there"? Probably not, because all your experience with water everywhere else tells you *it shouldn't be there*. This tunnel would cause the same issue.

Comment: @KeithMorrison, the data wouldn't show an empty tunnel. It would show strange reflections that would be consistent with a tunnel, or some other weird rock formation.

Comment: @o.m. That's not how modern seismic surveys work. Analysis of the pressure waves that are generated by the source and picked up by the geophone array take into account not just reflection of the wave but the way the wave refracts when passing through materials of different density as the velocity changes. Passing through a long, linear void in otherwise solid rock would show a "layer" of such low density that it should be impossible, and therefore would immediately attract attention. A detailed survey would be able to determine that is was, essentially, empty space.

Comment: @KeithMorrison, modern seismic science has been *calibrated* on a normal world. In this fictional world, the old scientists would tell the young one: *"That's how* enter-name-here *lines ten miles deep always look. It's deceptive. Read* enter-another-name-here's *paper how to compensate, or people will think you're suggesting they're **really** caves. You would become a laughingstock."* Think of astronomers correcting Newtonian physics with Einstein's model, except that in this case the simple model is truth and the correction is in fact wrong.

Comment: @o.m. That's not how *science* works, let alone geology (I'm a geologist). Part of the science of geology (and all sciences) is questioning the why of something, not simply brushing it off as "Oh, that's just the way it is." If there was a narrow linear feature that circled the entire planet (what was proposed in the original question), people aren't going to simply accept it's there and move on, there will be theories as to why such a clearly anomalous feature, given the way the rest of the planet looks, is there, and people actively seeking to verify those theories.

Comment: And when geologists get an understanding of plate tectonics, there will be further questions as to why such a feature exists because it quite clearly should be *impossible* as it would be contradicting all other evidence showing plate movement, spreading centers, and subduction.

Comment: @KeithMorrison, science is **also** about selecting the theory that explains the experimental data in a consistent way. If reality is weird and the theory explains that away, Occam's Razor would suggest to take the theory.

Comment: Keith is right. Sure, the geophysicists _in the field_ would mostly just “compensate for the effect”, and focus on features of more immediate interest. But such an anomaly would attract hordes of theoreticians who would cook up concrete models to explain it as precisely as possible; it would probably sprout completely new experimental methods, etc. etc.. Yes, the first people to suggest the _tunnel hypothesis_ would meet a lot of scepticism, but as soon as their predictions for _a future measurement_ turn out to be more accurate than anything before, the community would take them seriously.

Comment: A good analogy might be the [Pioneer anomaly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pioneer_anomaly): a really rather tiny discrepancy between measured and expected acceleration, which could easily have been attributed to just _systematic measurement error_. But no, the scientists would not give the matter a rest before – among many more spectacular hypotheses – a mundane explanation through thermal recoil force became accepted, since it was able to explain the effect _without any new physics_.

Comment: Exactly right. Someone using a seismic survey to say, look for oil, would just "compensate" because explaining anomalies that aren't related to petroleum reservoirs isn't their job. On the other hand, a geophysicist interested in the structure of the crust would be very interested in knowing what the hell was going on with such an anomaly.

Comment: @KeithMorrison, you are right that people would talk about the anomaly. Even write papers about it. But any scientists who says "yes, they really are tunnels, that is the best explanation" would have to answer how those tunnels could survive down there, assuming they were natually formed. Or admit that his explanation is inconsistent with all we know about lava tubes. Blaming aliens would put those scientists right into the tinfoil hats divison.

Comment: That wasn't the original question: it was how long could something like that get overlooked. And the answer was: it wouldn't.

Comment: @KeithMorrison, if the mainstream scientific community rejects it that qualifies as "overlooked," I think.

Answer (score 8):

If I were the aliens and wanted to hide the tunnel **I would align this tunnel with the mid-ocean ridges**.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mid-ocean_ridge

> The mid-ocean ridges of the world are connected and form the Ocean
>   Ridge, a single global mid-oceanic ridge system that is part of every
>   ocean, making it the longest mountain range in the world. The
>   continuous mountain range is 65,000 km (40,400 mi) long (several times
>   longer than the Andes, the longest continental mountain range), and
>   the total length of the oceanic ridge system is 80,000 km (49,700 mi)
>   long.[6]

[image: mid ocean ridges from wikipedia]

The ridges are formed by the motion of plates away from each other.  It is not a symmetric ring but it is ringish; the real ridges do go around the earth, mostly, in a somewhat meandering way.  Especially that Indian ridge.  A structure on one side of the plate boundary would be carried away from the boundary, but the accumulated stone there should not flex or distort too much.  Clearly though, unless the aliens built this thing just 6,000 years ago, the engineering of the tunnel is going to have to accommodate some flex.  I think a civilization capable of building such a thing would probably not make it out of mud bricks.  Some sort of crystalline structure capable of compensating for gradual movement is not outrageous.

The mid ocean ridges are deep and not well explored.

http://oceanexplorer.noaa.gov/facts/mid-ocean-ridge.html

> Like the rest of the deep-ocean floor, we have explored less of the
>   mountains of the Mid-Ocean Ridge system than the surface of Venus,
>   Mars, or the dark side of the Moon. Use of submersible or remotely
>   operated vehicles to explore the mid-ocean ridge has provided
>   information on less than 0.1 percent of the ridge!

If someone were examining at a ridge, a (barely seen) deep geological feature aligned with the long axis of the ridge would likely be assumed to be natural in origin.

I like the idea that the persons discovering this tunnel system realizes that its makers not only bored out the tunnels but also engineered the plates themselves to serve their purposes.  Tunnel explorers: watch out for shoggoths!

Comment: Tekeli-li! Tekeli-li!

Comment: @Will "*but also engineered the plates themselves to serve their purposes.*" that would require the makers to have engineered the plates billions of years ago.

Comment: You overlooked the obvious cause of the ridges - they're a side effect of the tunneling technology! The power to the maintenance field surrounding the tunnels was slightly mis-calculated by a summer intern, resulting in a miniscule gravity overload which is slowly but constantly sucking the plates together into a ridge over the tunnels, and tearing them away from the divergent plate boundaries. ...or maybe it was deliberate, and the intern wanted a self-destruct mechanism slow enough to not implicate him until he had a new job.

Comment: ... and of course, you also forgot the secondary set of access / maintenance tunnels running underneath the [continental divides](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ee5rE.png). The Himalayas and the Chilean Andes obviously have either redundancy or larger capacity, and Antarctica and Greenland are revealed to be major connection hubs, no doubt with additional climate-control measures taken to make those areas undesirable for surface habitation (and the pesky exploration drilling that comes with it).

Comment: @RonJohn - having engineered them does not mean they made them.  People engineer mountains to make it easier for railways to traverse them.  Those engineers got to the mountains some time after they were formed.  Likewise the plates and these alien engineers.

Comment: @Will "*having engineered them does not mean they made them*" ignores where they came from.

Answer (score 5):

It would have been found decades ago.

Earthquake surveys act as a deep level sonar and show up large structures inside the earth. This allows for discovery of the inner and outer core, good estimates about their structure and chemical composition. The mantle has a velocity change called the Morohovicic discontinuity that is due to small changes in density that was found over a century ago https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohorovi%C4%8Di%C4%87_discontinuity

A tunnel full of air would have a *very* sharp density change and this would give rise to sesmic wave reflections and refractions and these would show up on large scale surveys and data collections. The same technique is used these days to look ad descending plate fragments and these only have subtle density changes - an air filled tunnel would stick out like a beacon. Whilst not something that could be easily investigated at the time - this would have been found in the early part of the 20th century.

Comment: +1: Even if it wasn't full of air, the fact that it's a single continuous structure would have seismic vibrations traveling along it at a constant speed that's very different to the rock around it. This would be noticed, unless it was specifically built to dampen seismic vibrations, essentially it would ring like a bell. As

Comment: Also, if it deforms / breaks with seismic activity it won't remain a ring for very long. Also it will "break" differently to the rock around it, making it obvious that there's something there. If it doesn't break then it's going to be even more conspicuous, as the forces will move around it, showing that there's something very odd happening in that location.

Answer (score 1):

**Flood it**

Make sure the tunnel runs almost exclusively underwater and flood it with seawater. Seismographic equipment and measurements probably won't detect it, likewise any "deep" radar technologies that might exist in your world.
It'll basically blend in.

Comment: It will be detected. A seismic study will trivially pick up the difference in density between a granite pluton (average specific gravity 2.75) and the basalt it's in (average specific gravity 2.9) without trying hard. Picking out the difference between rock and a tunnel full of water (specific gravity about 1) is child's play.

Answer (score -1):

If it is on earth, or being observed by mankind; generally speaking people ignore what they can't easily explain or try explaining with old ideas rather the. Form new ones. In a sense you could have this mega structure above ground and covered with half a mile of rock and  have it sit long enough and everyone would consider it normal or explain it away. Vise versa those who who look for contact generally see it everywhere.

Answer (score -1):

They could have the TARDIS effect and  be in a tiny sphere.One would think that they could even be under a desert with some advanced shielding.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding! As this question is a [tag:reality-check] question, the preferred answers would generally be 'harder-science' (much more realistic) than the likes of the TARDIS, unless specified otherwise in the question, so would you be able to [edit] your answer to take this into account? Thanks